# name of file changed when downloading pdf File from database

Tags: c#, sql-server

i save pdf file in database , and after i downloading it from the database, i see that its name is completly changed to something like Code , can you explain me why? and how to resolve this to get the same name of pdf file? here is the code :

**Insert**

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.ShowDialog();
        byte[] file;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                file = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
            }
        }
        SqlConnection varConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\sqlexpress;Database=badge;integrated security=yes");
        varConnection.Open();
        using (var sqlWrite = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO archive Values(@dat,@disponible,@fil)", varConnection))
        {
            sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@dat", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Today;
            sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@disponible", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = comboBox1.Text;

            sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@fil", SqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = file;
            sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        varConnection.Close();
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.ShowDialog();
        byte[] file;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                file = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
            }
        }
        SqlConnection varConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\sqlexpress;Database=badge;integrated security=yes");
        varConnection.Open();
        using (var sqlWrite = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO archive Values(@dat,@disponible,@fil)", varConnection))
        {
            sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@dat", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Today;
            sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@disponible", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = comboBox1.Text;

            sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@fil", SqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = file;
            sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        varConnection.Close();
```

download :

```
SqlConnection varConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\sqlexpress;Database=badge;integrated security=yes");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select fil from archive where dat = '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and disponible='"+comboBox1.Text+"'";
        cmd.Connection = varConnection;
        varConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader sqlRead = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        SaveFileDialog svd = new SaveFileDialog();
        svd.ShowDialog();
        if (sqlRead.HasRows)
        {
            while (sqlRead.Read())
            {
                byte[] fileData = (byte[])sqlRead[0];
                BinaryWriter fileCreate =
                    new BinaryWriter(File.Open(svd.FileName, FileMode.Create));
                fileCreate.Write(fileData);
                fileCreate.Close();
            }
        }
        varConnection.Close();
```

Comment: did you read what your code does? it's very clear if you read it...

Answer (score 1):

You do not seem to save and fetch original filename and also you are taking it from the `SaveFileDialog`

```
SaveFileDialog svd = new SaveFileDialog();
// ...
// svd.FileName is used, that is, user provided file name for the saved file
BinaryWriter fileCreate =  new BinaryWriter(File.Open(svd.FileName, FileMode.Create));
```

You should do the following:

1. Save the original filename in the database (`ofd.FileName`)
2. Retrieving it when selection is performed (`cmd.CommandText = "select fil, filename from archive where dat = "`)

P.S. There are also some other problems with your code that you should tackle

1. Dispose `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` by putting them in `using` blocks
2. `cmd.CommandText = "select fil from archive where dat = '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and disponible='"+comboBox1.Text+"'";` should be parameterized, not obtained through string concatenation